# CSS. Затемнение всей страницы

Tags: css

Пытаюсь сделать затемнение всей страницы с гифкой в прелоаде. Затемнение опускается только на видимую часть страницы при загрузке в браузере, все остальное при скролле остается без затемнения. Как это растянуть на всю страницу целиком?

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="page-preloader"></div>
</div>

.container {
    height: 1000px;
}

#page-preloader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /*background: #2c2c2c;*/
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oacq42xk/3/

Comment: Вместо `position: absolute` надо `position: fixed`

Comment: @zhurof, чего не в ответы-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/8thsenc3/

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: `height: 100vh;` ?)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, куда и зачем? Наоборот.

Answer (score -2):

Добавь в css:

```
HTML, body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

А в container:

```
diplay:block;  
width: 100%;  
height: 100%;
```